# Bilinear interpolation color scheme

Tags: c#, colors, interpolation, lookup

I'm currently working on a Mandelbrot fractal generator program in C#. For a coloring scheme, I'm using a linear interpolation and an array as a lookup table.

The problem with linear interpolation is that I can only use two colors.

I would like to use at least three colors and I've been looking around for a bilinear interpolation programming algorithm but I haven't found any good ones.

I was wondering if any of you might have a solution to this.

Here is my linear interpolation code:

```
private void InitColors()
{
    int range = 255;
    lookup = new Color[range];
    Color from = Color.White;
    Color to = Color.Blue;
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;

    for (int i = 0; i < range; i++)
    {
        red = ((from.R * (range - i)) + (to.R * i)) / range;
        green = ((from.G * (range - i)) + (to.G * i)) / range;
        blue = ((from.B * (range - i)) + (to.B * i)) / range;
        lookup[i] = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Perhaps there is a more simple interpolation than the bilinear to get a gradient between more than two colors. I don't really care which method as long as it gets the job done :-)

Comment: It's clear that linear interpolation gives you a gradient between two colors. But if you want to interpolate over three colors, then you need (at least) two degrees of freedom. What exactly are the (two or more) variables that you want to use to drive the color selection? Recursion depth? X coordinate? Distance from an arbitrary point in the plane?

Comment: I don't really care what method to use, as long as I get the result of a gradient between more than two colors. But I would like a pretty simple one, if it does exist :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're after is not really called bilinear interpolation. Bilinear implies a 2D colour map using two arguments i and j in 0-1 range and blends four colors using those two i,j values  - i.e.

```
C = C_00 (1-i) (1-j) + C_10 * i * (1-j) + C_01 * (1-i) * j + C_11 * i * j
```

where C_ij are the corner colours.

If I understand you correctly what you really want is to be able to create a gradient that involves more than one color, but is still one dimensional, using a single parameter. To do this there is a variety of methods. The simplest of these is to blend from color A to color B over the 0-0.5 range and B to C over the 0.5 to 1.0 range.

You can of course divide up into more colours than just 3...

Code to do this would look something like this:

```
private void InitColors( Color * colors, int n_colors)
{
    int range = 255;
    lookup = new Color[range];
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;

    for (int i = 0; i < range; i++)
    {
        float f = float(i)/float(range);
        //Work out which interval we're in
        int interval = f*(n_colors);

        //Special case for the end point to prevent out-of-bounds access. 
        if(f>=1.0) { interval = n_colors-1; }

        //Work out how far into that interval we are
        float ff = f * (n_colors-1) - interval;

        int R = (colors[interval].R * (1-f) + colors[interval+1].R*f;
        int G = (colors[interval].G * (1-f) + colors[interval+1].G*f;
        int B = (colors[interval].B * (1-f) + colors[interval+1].B*f;

        lookup[i] = Color.FromArgb(R, G, B);
    }
}
```

Now there's a couple of issues with this that you probably will not care about, but I'll mention just in case:

- This is not a very smooth color transition. If you want smoother behaviour you'll need to use a spline based approach (which technically this is the simplest version of). I'd suggest looking into Cattmul-Rom splines for this.
- The color transitions are not very uniform or nice. I'd consider doing the calculations in a space other than RGB and converting back to RGB at the end. For this I'd consider `Lab` space (HSV is another option, but then you need to worry about wrapping in the H direction.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Bilinear implies two arguments i and j" what do those arguments signify?

Comment: Clarified that with an example (hopefully).

Comment: So they're arbitrary coefficients?

Comment: you can view i,j as indexes into a 2D colour patch, rather than what the OP seems to want, which is a 1D lookup that contains multiple colours.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in your code, every color may be represented as a vector  in Euclidean 3 space.

So given 3 arbitrary colors C1, C2, and C3, first find the associated RGB vectors v1, v2, v3, and then construct the triangular region with a vertex at the tip of each vector by taking all "convex combinations" of these 3 vectors:

```
c1 * v1 + c2 * v2 + c3 * v3
```

where c1, c2, and c3 are scalar values between 0 and 1, and c1 + c2 + c3 = 1, and the usual Euclidean rules of vector addition (and scalar multiplication) apply.

**NOTE:** This also works for an arbitrary number of colors. For N colors you have N associated vectors, and the "convex combinations" of these vectors is an N-1 dimensional "simplex". It's all linear, and very easy to calculate. But the color gradient produced this way may not be aesthetically optimal - a non-linear method may produce a more beautiful result.

**EDIT:** Geometrically speaking your "simplex" with N vertices will not actually be N-1 dimensional if N > 3, because your "vectors" all live in RGB space which is 3 dimensional, and so cannot all be linearly independent. This means there will generally (for N > 3) be many points in the "simplex" with different coordinates but the same apparent "color".

Comment: What do you do with the triangular region?